# Handling RabbitMQ heartbeats when cpu is loaded 100% for a long time

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, pika, graph-tool

I'm using pika 1.1 and graph-tool 3.4 in my python application. It consumes tasks from RabbitMQ, which then used to build graphs with graph-tool and then runs some calculations.

Some of the calculations, such as betweenness, take a lot of cpu power which make cpu usage hit 100% for a long time. Sometimes rabbitmq connection drops down, which causes task to start from the beginning.

Even though calculations are run in a separate process, my guess is during the time cpu is loaded 100%, it can't find any opportunity to send a heartbeat to rabbitmq, which causes connection to terminate. This doesn't happen all the time, which indicates by chance it could send heartbeats time to time. This is only my guess, I am not sure what else can cause this.

I tried lowering the priority of the calculation process using `nice(19)`, which didn't work. I'm assuming it's not affecting the processes spawned by graph-tool, which parallelizes work on its own.

Since it's just one line of code, `graph.calculate_betweenness(...` I don't have a place to manually send heartbeats or slow the execution down to create chance for heartbeats.

1. Can my guess about heartbeats not getting sent because cpu is super busy be correct?
2. If yes, how can I handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Answering to your questions:

1. Yes, that's basically it.
2. The solution we do is creating a separate process for the CPU intensive tasks.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()


channel.exchange_declare(exchange='logs', exchange_type='fanout')
result = channel.queue_declare(queue='', exclusive=True)
queue_name = result.method.queue
channel.queue_bind(exchange='logs', queue=queue_name)


def cpu_intensive_task(ch, method, properties, body):

    def work(body):
        time.sleep(60)  # If I remember well default HB is 30 seconds
        print(" [x] %r" % body)

    p = Process(target=work, args=(body,))
    p.start()
    # Important to notice if you do p.join() You will have the same problem.

channel.basic_consume(
    queue=queue_name, on_message_callback=cpu_intensive_task, auto_ack=True)

channel.start_consuming()
```

I wonder if this is the best solution to this problem or if rabbitMQ is the best tool for CPU intensive tasks. (For really long CPU intensive tasks (more than 30 min) if you send manual ACK you will need to handle with this also: https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#acknowledgement-timeout)